# Error While Fitting johnsonFit

Tags: r

I am trying to use johnsonFit in "SuppDists" package in R to fit distribution to my data. For most of the columns of the data it works fine except for some I get the following error:

> Error in JohnsonFit(x, moment = "quant") : 
>   Unbounded solution intermediate values out of range.

Is there a way to fix this problem? I know there might be problem with the raw data, but not sure what it is and how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some sort of [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can help you troubleshoot what's going on.

Comment: My data is BIG! 111, 645 rows. I notice that this particular data has lots of zeros. Here is a summary of the data:                                                       
  Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.000   0.000   1.000   2.927   3.000 109.000

Comment: A reproducible example doesn’t have to include all your data. But if we are unable to reproduce the problem, we are unable to help.

Comment: Here is the reproducible example:
library(SuppDists)
data <- c(0,5,0,2,0,1,4,0,0,6,0,1,0,1,0,1,2,2,3,1,1,88,0,0,2,3,0,6,2,3,9,13,1,1,3,0,1,0,3,1,1,0,0,2,1,0,0,67,1,6,
          11,2,0,4,1,1,10,4,4,3,0,0,0,5,1,1,0,4,1,2,0,6,0,1,2,3,7,5,0,2,0,1,7,0,2,0,6,4,1,2,0,1,7,1,7,1,0,1,0,0)

JohnsonFit(data)
The error I get is:
Error in JohnsonFit(data) : 
Unbounded solution intermediate values out of range